# Unable to remove an item or empty cart correctly

Tags: php

I've tried enough to remove an item from session or empty the cart to no avail. Items are stored in array but couldn't remove them and after clicked on remove,it removes all items and leaves only one in the cart.After I empty the cart,when I attempt to add item to the cart it says the error below:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ')' at line 1

I found the code that giving this error, apparently the query to display add on items.Which is

```
$colname_RecAdd_on = $id['add_on'];
mysql_select_db($database);
$query_add = "SELECT * FROM tbl_addons WHERE addOns_id IN ($colname_RecAdd_on)";

$result_add=mysql_query($query_add)or die(mysql_error());
```

And my codes to remove the items from session is like this:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
$id=$_GET['id'];
$_SESSION['items']=array();

for($i=0; $i < count($_SESSION['items']); $i++)
{
   if($_SESSION['items'][$i] == $id)
   {
      unset($_SESSION['items'][$id]);   
   }
}
```

Can anybody help me on this privately and immediately? Thanks a lot...

Comment: What does `$colname_RecAdd_on` hold?

Comment: `var_dump()` the `$query_add` var, you have to. And the error you will find. Mhm.

Comment: Most probably that variable `$colname_RecAdd_on` is empty

Comment: @Hanky exactly the $colname_RecAdd_on turns empty after clicking on remove link. Before that it holds items of addon inside. But i don't know why to solve it...

Comment: @Darren $colname_RecAdd_on is holding value of addon items for the car id

Comment: why r u doing this - $_SESSION['items']=array(); ??

Comment: @sgt to declare it as an array?

Comment: then why r u using unset on an empty array?

Comment: @sgt I got your point and I removed that line in remove.php. However it's not empty array ,the value stored inside it in add_cart.php like this:  $_SESSION['items'][$price]=array('total'=>$car_id,'add_on'=>$add_on);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already emptied the session and in the loop, trying to compare.

```
$_SESSION['items']=array();
```

For unset, there is no need to loop like that, as it seems static.
And the above line will prevent you entering the loop that executes the below code:

```
unset($_SESSION['items'][$id]);
```

**Suggested** without loop in the session data:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['items'][$id])
{
    unset($_SESSION['items'][$id]);
}
```

Comment: ,i removed $_SESSION['items']=array(); and tried only if(isset($_SESSION['items'][$id])
{
    unset($_SESSION['items'][$id]);
} but it's not removing. Probably because it stores array of values inside the session?